# Count the number of users that liked my post facebook app

Tags: javascript, facebook

I have a facebook application that post a feed regarding my application. Now what I want to know is how do I know the number of users who like that specific post?

Here's my code for creating a feed.

```
FB.ui({
        method: 'feed',
        link: 'https://apps.facebook.com/lnmapps',
        display: 'iframe',
        picture: '',
        message: 'my message',
        name: 'I have found this awesome app!',
        caption: 'LoyaltyNmore'
    }, fbCallback);
```

I've read some tutorials and I saw something like specifying the post url and do some checking but I don't really get it. Is there anyone who could guide me on this? Maybe some code snippet or javascript code? By the way, I'm using .Net MVC and javascript with my app. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Should be something like this:

```
FB.ui({
    method: 'feed',
    link: 'https://apps.facebook.com/lnmapps',
    display: 'iframe',
    picture: '',
    message: 'my message',
    name: 'I have found this awesome app!',
    caption: 'LoyaltyNmore'
}, function(new_post) {
    FB.api('/' + new_post.id, function(post) {
        alert(post.likes.length);
    });
});
```

From your FB.ui function you should get a response containing the id of the new post. Then make an api call for that post to get the likes.

Comment: So does that mean I have to save the new_post.id so if the user opens the app. I can load it and make an api call to check how many likes did his/her post get?

Comment: Yes... maybe with an ajax call to a php script or something like that

Comment: I think I can store this in my local DB with the userId because I will be needing it to detect the number of likes per user post/shares. Thanks! Great and accurate answer.

Comment: Follow up question though. I also want to count the number of repost of the current post. So I should use the same approach right?

Comment: yes, the number of shares is also included in the response of that api call where you get the likes.

Comment: I checked this answer but I get a error on my console. Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined. I copied it as it is. Sorry I unchecked the answer mark on your answer.

Comment: posts.likes is also undefined

Comment: I didn't say that this is THE answer but it should work somehow this way. Check out the Graph Api Explorer https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=100003234254504%3Ffields%3Did%2Cname